# C: How do I make lowercase input and uppercase input equal in strcmp?

Tags: c, function, warnings, void

I am writing a program in C and have one question.

First, let's say I have a scan for a string and then use strcmp.

~~scan for user input~~

```
if (strcmp(string,"meat") == 0)
    return 1;
```

How can I make it so that Meat,mEat,MEAT, etc will all be correct in this strcmp?

Thank you.

Comment: Note: 1) Converting both strings with `tolower()` or `toupper()`  is a classic approach but has a problem:  Other than the usual A-Z,a-z, some conversions are not 1 to 1 creating difference result between using the upper or lower method.  2) Any case insensitive compare that relies on the _sign_ of the response may get different results depend on if using the upper/lower methods like `if (stricmp("A","_")   > 0`.  Use http://stackoverflow.com/a/28592903/2410359

Answer (score 6):

Unix systems have `strcasecmp`. Windows has `stricmp`.

Comment: @BrianDeBoi Just remember that these are not in the C standard library.

Comment: This is why I said Unix not C... `strcasecmp` is POSIX compliant.